# Android-How to replace R.layout.id by custom relativelayout in CustomAdapter?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-inflate

```
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_ten_words,null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtSrc = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_src_word);
            holder.btnTranslate = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_translate);
            holder.txtDes = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_des_word);}`
```

Here , I want to use my RelativeLayout that I have created programmatically in place of R.layout.row_ten_words

Code that I want to use is:

```
          ` EditText txtSrc=new EditText(this);

    EditText txtDes=new EditText(this);

    Button btn_translate=new Button(this);

    translate.setText("translate");

     rl=new RelativeLayout(this);

    rl.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    rl.addView(txtSrc);

    rl.addView(btn_translate);

    rl.addView(txtDes);`
```

I am totally new to android but know JAVA well. Please suggest me something if I am wrong in my approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a new layout file ,Save in Layout folder and then pass reference here e.g. R.layout.your_layout_name.

Comment: @Brontok I need to make this layout in scratch. Designing should be using code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are essentially replacing the inflation of a View with your dynamic View creation. To create a View programmatically, you need a `Context` reference. You will need to add a class member and set it in the Adapter's constructor (this may not be exactly like yours, but you get the idea):

```
Context context;

public SomeAdapter(Context context, int resource)
{
    super(context, resource);

    this.context = context;
    ...
    ...
```

And then:

```
if (convertView == null)
{
    EditText txtSrc = new EditText(context);
    EditText txtDes = new EditText(context);
    Button btnTranslate = new Button(context);
    btnTranslate.setText("translate");

    rl = new RelativeLayout(context);
    rl.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    rl.addView(txtSrc);
    rl.addView(btn_translate);
    rl.addView(txtDes);

    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.txtSrc = txtSrc;
    holder.btnTranslate = btnTranslate;
    holder.txtDes = txtDes;

    convertView = rl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but method addView is not defined for View @Mike

Comment: ClassCastException in convertView=rl;

Comment: hmm ok..m new to android....any suggestion will be appreciated..thanks for the help

Comment: 03-13 06:18:11.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2351): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
03-13 06:18:11.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2351):  at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1167)
03-13 06:18:11.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2351):  at 03-13 06:18:11.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2351):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
03-13 06:18:11.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2351):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
03-13 06:18:11.41

Comment: 03-13 07:23:28.997: E/AndroidRuntime(2939): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
03-13 07:23:28.997: E/AndroidRuntime(2939):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.findRoots(RelativeLayout.java:1723)

Comment: I am Using the following code...but it is giving above error...RelativeLayout convert = new RelativeLayout(context);
       convert.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
       convert.addView(txtSrc);
       convert.addView(btnTranslate);
       convert.addView(txtDes);
       
       holder = new ViewHolder();
       holder.txtSrc = txtSrc;
       holder.btnTranslate = btnTranslate;
       holder.txtDes = txtDes;
       convertView=convert;

Comment: No, no. You need to use `AbsListView.LayoutParams`, __not__ `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.

Comment: Even after using AbsListView it is giving samme exception as above. M doing this coz somemone have asked me to do it without xml.

Comment: To set the position of widgets according to different device screen resolution on percentage basis.

Comment: In XML we can give only fixed size.....moreover I am eager to know if we can do it this way or not...in xml it is working perfectly fine

Comment: I am missing somethin somewhere.....lack of experience in android...even after changing to RelativeLayout.LayoutParams and AbsListView.LayoutParams .....the cast exception shows that ViewGroup LayoutParams can not be casted into RelativeLayout params. Which means changes arn't having any effect. the layout params for convert remain ViewGroup.LayoutParams

Comment: By the way...thanx a lot for helping me...M new to this site too...can we add users here for future reference??

Comment: your email id??? By adding users I mean if I want to cantact you in future to clearify any doubts...Is it possible?